# Using asychronous function inside of Jupyter Widget event listener

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I am having troubles getting on_start_change, on_end_change, and on_customer_change to work as intended due to those functions being asynchronous. Is there a way to run asynchronous functions in ipywidgets.observe() or a workaround?
`start_date.observe(on_start_change, names="value") end_date.observe(on_end_change, names="value") customer_widget.observe(on_customer_change, names="value")`

When I try this, I get the error: object function can't be used in 'await' expression.
`start_date.observe(await on_start_change, names="value") end_date.observe(await on_end_change, names="value") customer_widget.observe(await on_customer_change, names="value")`